# How to catch syntax errors in included files in PHP?

Tags: php, plugins, error-handling, syntax-error

I'm developing a plugin system, which of course needs to `include` the plugin files. So far everything works very well - exceptions get catched etc.

But my very last wish would be to even be safe from corrupt plugin files containing syntax errors. Is there a way to catch Fatal Errors in included files?

Answer (score 4):

There is [runkit_lint()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-lint.php) that requires PHP runkit, or simply run `php` with the `-l` option for Lint:

```
if(strpos(exec('/path/to/php -l filename.php'), 'No syntax errors detected') !== false) {
    // file parses :-)
} else {
    // parse errors :-(
}
```

Or similar logic.  Note that this only checks for parse errors not fatal errors (require fails, etc.)

Comment: So basically I need to precheck every file before actually including it? Is runkit eventually cheaper in terms of performance?

Comment: I haven't bench-marked, but you could lint the files once and save the "safe" ones in the db or file and check that on subsequent calls and only check new files.